# django profies and request.user - error

Tags: django, django-users, django-profiles

I'm getting the following error:

> 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'get_profile'

after I added the following middleware, and try to log on to my site without having logged on before:

```
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            driver = request.user.get_profile()
            timezone.activate(driver.timezone)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            timezone.activate('UTC')
```

In the traceback, the error occurs at the first line of the try statement.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: protect the line by 'if request.user.is_authenticated():'

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I am happy to mark your answer as the correct one if you submit it as an answer.  Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-logged in users, `request.user` is `AnonymousUser` instance, which does not contain `get_profile`. We could check whether an `request.user` has been logged in and protect logic for logged-in users by [`if request.user.is_authenticated():`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated)

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
        try:
            driver = request.user.get_profile()
            timezone.activate(driver.timezone)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            timezone.activate('UTC')
```

Answer (score 0):

request.user.get_profile() probably raises an AttributeError, you should try the following

```
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            driver = request.user.get_profile()
            timezone.activate(driver.timezone)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist, AttributeError:
            timezone.activate('UTC')
```