# Django Middleware to Extend self.request for a social media apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

We know in Django, we can access to too many instances in `self.request` like `self.request.user`, `self.request.data`, `self.request.authenticator` etc

I am trying to get `self.request.mygroup` writing custom middleware

this is my models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    auth_user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='auth_user',
    )

class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        related_name='group_members'
    )
```

I wrote this middleware and it is working fine:

```
class GroupMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        person = Person.objects.filter(
            auth_user__id=request.user.id
        ).first()
        mygroup = Group.objects.filter(
            members__alias__in=[person.alias]
        )
        request.mygroup = mygroup.first()
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Above middleware working fine but the problem is when I visit from incognito mode, I mean when I am not logged in, it throws me an error like AnonymouseUser doesn't have attribute `self.request.user`

to handle this, I tried writing condition like if `self.request.user.is_authenticated:` but it occurs another error as same. I guess I crafted the middleware wrongly, Can anyone help me to extend `self.request` to get my own instance like `self.request.mygroup`?

I am not getting what is the right way to write a middleware, i am very new in middleware

I want `self.request.mygroup` should retun only authinticated user's group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Django user, but it sounds like you are checking the wrong thing.

self.request.user.is_authenticated

is also throwing an error because they are not authenticated so the user is null, so maybe try checking if self.request.user is null? and only checking the next bit if it is not null.

From The [Documentation](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser)

django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser is a class that implements the django.contrib.auth.models.User interface, with these differences:

```
id is always None.
username is always the empty string.
get_username() always returns the empty string.
is_staff and is_superuser are always False.
is_active is always False.
groups and user_permissions are always empty.
is_anonymous() returns True instead of False.
is_authenticated() returns False instead of True.
set_password(), check_password(), save() and delete() raise NotImplementedError.
```

Possibly also here: [django profies and request.user - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125688/django-profies-and-request-user-error)

Comment: AnonymouseUser doesn't have attribute self.request.user That says that self.request.user doesnt exist when you have an AnonymousUser